# What resources on OpenVMS Performance Management do you recommend?

Tags: performance, performance-tuning, openvms

I'm looking for details about how to measure OpenVMS performance, such as what all of the different reported statistics mean and how to adjust for them.

In particular, I'm currently investigating OpenVMS memory management; any specifics would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One answer: [OpenVMS Performance Management](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/73final/documentation/pdf/OVMS_73_perf_mang.PDF) and maybe other stuff at [HP OpenVMS Systems](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/).

Comment: I didn't think they had anything like that.  In any case, this doc is for OpenVMS 7.3 for Alpha and VAX - not 8.3 for Itanium.  Still might be some things of interest, though.

Comment: I'm curious: you didn't think they had anything like what? Manuals? Performance Management manuals? That book, or something very like it has been part of the OpenVMS doc set since it was the "VAX/VMS" doc set.